# Accessing methods and variables through super in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement the below code, but I am getting an error in class HistoryStudent extends Student, sGrade. How do I go about adding the student grade through super? 
This is an assignment and we are not supposed to change anything in the abstract class or any part of the below code.

```
abstract class Student
{
    private String studentID    =   "" ;
    private int studentGrade    =   0 ;

    public Student (String sID, int sGrade)
    {
        studentID       = sID  ;
        studentGrade    = sGrade ;

        return ;
    }


    public String getStudentID      () { return studentID       ;}
    public double getStudentGrade   () { return studentGrade    ;}


    boolean updateGrade (int grade)
    {
        boolean check = false ;

        studentGrade += grade;

        return check ;
    }

}

class HistoryStudent extends Student
{
    public HistoryStudent (String sID, int sGrade)
    {
        super(sID,sGrade) ;


        return ;
    }


    boolean updateGrade (int grade)
    {
        boolean checking = false ;

            //Problem here
        **sGrade** += grade;

        return checking ;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: what issue u face in the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change update method in HistoryStudent class.

```
boolean updateGrade(int grade)

{
    boolean checking = false ;
    super.updateGrade(grade);
    return checking ;
}
```

Comment: Basically this will call parent class updateGrade(int grade) method which can only make changes to its private attributes like studentID and studentGrade .

Answer (score 1):

```
//Problem here
**sGrade** += grade;   //Line mention in code
```

`sGrade` is local variable declare in the `HistoryStudent` constructor so you cant access it in the `updateGrade` method.

What you can do is declare the `sGrade` as global variable and while calling the super constructor in the method set the global variable value and access it in the `updateGrade` method.

```
class HistoryStudent extends Student
{
    int sGrade;

    public HistoryStudent (String sID, int sGrade)
    {
        super(sID,sGrade) ;
        this.sGrade = sGrade;
    }


    boolean updateGrade (int grade)
    {
        boolean checking = false ;
        sGrade += grade;    // Dnt know usage bcoz everytime method will return false
        return checking ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the super class for `updateGrade (int grade)` which does exactly what you want to do.